# Wicket: Best practice for deployment to avoid ClassNotFoundException

Tags: deployment, wicket, web-deployment, classnotfoundexception, wicket-6

I'm new to wicket and just recently started to use it for a new web
app for one of our projects. Today I came across a similar issue like
described in [WICKET-4785](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4785), a ClassNotFoundException during deserialization of a
page. The interesting part about this in my mind is, that the
mentioned missing class was missing for a good reason: I simply
refactored a bit and renamed the class, redeployed and restarted my
Tomcat. This looks like a normal use case to me, but is something I
didn't thought of when I've read through the docs because.

My deployment is very simple: I check out a SVN working copy with a
pre-configured tag containing the whole application once and
afterwards just need to merge/update and stop/start the web
server/app.

How is deployment supposed to work in Wicket after I have refactored
or otherwise changed my classes regarding cached and serialized pages?
Is there anything I need to tell wicket to clear its caches on each
deployment or ignore those or whatever? Am I forced to not delete once
deployed classes for a fair period of time? That would be a litte
nightmare... Or is there any other issue I ran into I should have
avoided?

Obviously others do deploy their Wicket apps as well, so I hope you
have some input on how to avoid the problem I've ran into. Thanks!

The important parts of the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.am_soft.util.frontend.wicket.markup.link.LogoutLink
     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.wicket.application.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:108)
     at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer$ClassResolverObjectInputStream.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.java:218)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.[...]
     at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer.deserialize(JavaSerializer.java:122)
     at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DefaultPageStore.deserializePage(DefaultPageStore.java:396)
     at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DefaultPageStore.getPage(DefaultPageStore.java:135)
     at org.apache.wicket.page.PageStoreManager$SessionEntry.getPage(PageStoreManager.java:203)
     at org.apache.wicket.page.PageStoreManager$PersistentRequestAdapter.getPage(PageStoreManager.java:360)
     at org.apache.wicket.page.AbstractPageManager.getPage(AbstractPageManager.java:107)
```

I posted this question on the [Wicket users list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/wicket-users/201411.mbox/%3C1634199932.20141121172209%40am-soft.de%3E) as well, but didn't get much response yet, although I thought this is an easy question...

Answer (score 2):

Wicket is a stateful web framework that stores page instances to facilitate a tight user interaction between browser and server. This means serializing the component hierarchy of each page so a user can interact with the component hierarchy, modify it (replacing panels for example) and expect the client and server to be in sync.

When you refactor your classes such as renaming a link class, the deserializer can't find that class and you get this ClassNotFoundException. To mitigate this you:

a. need to start a new session in your browser so that Wicket doesn't tie your browser to the server state with the old classes (throw the jsessionid cookie away), or

b. construct a new page instance inside your session (remove the ?0 or ?1231 parameter in the URL in your browser), or

c. clear all session data on the server

Comment: (b) is obviously no option for my users, (a) sounds like that my users get logged out for no reason and (c) means I have to deal with Wickets own cache file structure, which is an implementation detail and may change. Is this how other users really deploy? My own idea was the following: Catching (ClassNotFound/)RuntimeException in a DelegatingJavaSerializer and simply returning "null" in that case and let Wicket do it's job with creating new page instances automatically. It's described on the users list more detailled.

Comment: Now you are talking about users instead of development (the I in your question). Different use cases call for different solutions. Use BookmarkablePageLinks to navigate between pages so that the risk of hitting an out-of-date URL is minimized. Don't deploy a new application with each refactor to production (your users will thank you), deploy an application in a cluster and let the old sessions starve on the old version, and send new sessions to the new application version.

Comment: Of yourse I'm talking about "I", I'm the one deploying, production or not. ;-) I'll keep BookmarkablePageLinks in mind, thanks, but the other workarounds don't look like a practical solution to me. That would mean keeping buggy software around and we currently don't even use any clustering at all. I will try my DelegatingJavaSerializer approach and will see how that works. Wonder why Wicket behave the way it does...